# UiViewAnimation not call setAnimationDidStopSelector

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I created this animation and I entered through the stop animation

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (TermineAnimazioneGoPointAssignedWithDelay)] ;
```

When the animation part of the SetAnimationDidStop is not called ... Can you tell me why and where am I doing wrong ?

This is all the way animation :

```
-(void)setViewStatusGoPointassigned {
    ViewgoPointAssignMessage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115, 150, 100, 100) ];
    ViewgoPointAssignMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(77/255.0) green:(108/255.0) blue:(143/255.0) alpha:(1)];
    [ViewgoPointAssignMessage.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
    [ViewgoPointAssignMessage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

        ViewgoPointAssignMessage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05);
        ViewgoPointAssignMessage.alpha = 0.8; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2/15.0 animations:^{
                             ViewgoPointAssignMessage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
                             ViewgoPointAssignMessage.alpha = 0.9; }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:1/7.5 animations:^{
                                                  ViewgoPointAssignMessage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                                                  ViewgoPointAssignMessage.alpha = 1.0; } ];


                                          } ];
                     } ];

    [self.view addSubview:ViewgoPointAssignMessage];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(TermineAnimazioneGoPointAssignedWithDelay)];

}

-(void)TermineAnimazioneGoPointAssignedWithDelay {
    [self performSelector:@selector(EliminazioneViewAfterDelay) withObject:self afterDelay:0.01];
}
-(void)EliminazioneViewAfterDelay {
    CGRect endREct;
    endREct = CGRectMake(350 , 0 , 330, 90);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.005];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(EliminaAnimazione)];
     ViewgoPointAssignMessage.frame = endREct;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)EliminaAnimazione {
    [ViewgoPointAssignMessage removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to answer your question. 
You may try

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion]
```

and call `[self TermineAnimazioneGoPointAssignedWithDelay]` in the completion.

Secondly, `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(TermineAnimazioneGoPointAssignedWithDelay)]` doesn't work because according to the reference, setAnimationDidStopSelector must be called **between calls to the beginAnimations:context: and commitAnimations methods**. Since your code doesn't comply to this rule, the function does not work either.

Hopefully it explains! Good Luck!

Comment: No problem, always check the documentation:-)